# How to avoid Chatter being posted on creation for a specified record?

Tags: apex, community, chatter

I have FeedTracking enabled for a particular parent custom object and for the child object too. (The settings are such that creation of a child object, is also seen in the parent object's feed)
I have a custom field called "IsPrivate" on the child object. I want to implement a functionality wherein, if that field is set, no chatter is to be posted for the child object anywhere.

Please, can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Feed tracking for child object under FeedTracking Settings.
**Setup > Customize > Feed Tracking** > And *Uncheck **Enable Field Tracking** checkbox.*

Comment: Thank you Mukesh.
Maybe my problem statement was unclear.
Already on both my objects the feed tracking is enabled. My use case is such that, when a child object is create with the "isPrivate" field checked on it, I do not want the chatter to be posted on that particular record's creation.

Comment: @ShridharPuntambekar See this link - https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DfE0QAK, 

May be this patch bad, but might be work, you can delete chatter posts after records created which have "isPrivate" true.